# How can I make textboxes appear/disappear depending on a checkbox state?

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I have an application that I'm developing for a school project. This is what the application looks like
[image]

Essentially whenever one of the CheckBoxes is checked, a TextBox.Visible property is changed to true and is supposed to appear underneath the checkbox. You can have all three of them checked (or any combination checked) if you like, as long as when you uncheck it the TextBox disappears and the CheckBox appears empty/unchecked.

I've gotten to the point where I can make the TextBoxes appear and disappear but the TextBoxes are never empty. There's always a black square there that looks like this
[image]

Those black squares don't go away and I'm not sure exactly what the problem is. The TextBox also only appears when the CheckBox has that square as opposed to an actual check which is what is required. I have used a combination of If...ElseIf statements and Select Cases, which haven't done it. I've tried a few different events like CheckChanged and Click.

This is the code that I currently use that allows me to toggle the boxes.

```
Private Sub chkBox_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkBox.Click

    If chkBox.Checked = False Then
        txtBox.Visible = False
        txtBox.Text = ""
    Else
        txtBox.Visible = True
    End If
    chkBox.Checked = True

End Sub

Private Sub chkLawn_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkLawn.Click

    If chkLawn.Checked = False Then
        txtLawn.Visible = False
        txtLawn.Text = ""
    Else
        txtLawn.Visible = True
    End If
    chkLawn.Checked = True


End Sub

Private Sub chkPav_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkPav.Click
    If chkPav.Checked = False Then
        txtPav.Visible = False
        txtPav.Text = ""
    Else
        txtPav.Visible = True
    End If
    chkPav.Checked = True
End Sub
```

If you guys can think of a solution or could point me in the right direction I would appreciate that.

Comment: Please take a moment to read the site guidelines in the [help] on how to ask questions on Stack Overflow. All the *relevant* code (and only the relevant code) should be **in** the question - no outside links. Use the [edit] link below the question to make any changes. Also, VBA has nothing to do with Visual Studio. I assume VB.NET is meant and will alter the tags accordingly.

Comment: Posting images of code usually makes people downvote a question.  Always post the code as text, with a four space indent.  Why do you always set the checkbox Checked value to true?

Comment: did you know you can do things like `txtPav.Visible = chkPav.Checked`. Doing this inside of the CheckChangedEvent of the checkbox will trigger the code every time the state of the checkbox changes. A lot less code. You can even combine handles so that you can put all the code in the same event.

Comment: You wrote "the TextBoxes are never empty. There's always a black square there..." Are you referring to the black square in the *checkboxes*, which indicates they are in an indeterminate state, or are you referring to the box for, e.g., "Total tickets", which has a line visible?

Comment: What's the checkboxes' `ThreeState` property value? Make sure it's `false`.

Comment: Also, Boolean literal assignment to Boolean properties in both branches of a conditional is highly suspicious. See if `txtBox.Visible = chkBox.Checked` and `If Not chkBox.Checked Then txtBox.Text = ""` can replace that whole `If...Else` logic. Your checkboxes also appear to be impossible to un-check, since they're all unconditionally `.Checked = True` in their respective `Click` handler.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend this in the form load to setup a relationship between the checkboxes and the textboxes:

```
chkBox.Tag = txtBox
chkLawn.Tag = txtLawn
chkPav.Tag = txtPav
```

Then one handler:

```
Private Sub chkBox_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkBox.Click, chkPav.Click, chkLawn.Click
     CType(sender.Tag, TextBox).Visible = CType(sender, Checkbox).Checked
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

This will handle all your CheckBox.CheckChanged events. It finds the TextBox based on the name of the CheckBox. So just name them the same as you have (i.e. chkA and txtA).

```
Private textBoxPrefix As String = "txt"
Private checkBoxPrefix As String = "chk"

Private Sub chk_CheckedChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles chkBox.CheckedChanged, chkLawn.CheckedChanged, chkPav.CheckedChanged
    Dim chk = CType(sender, CheckBox)
    Dim suffix = chk.Name.Substring(checkBoxPrefix.Length)
    Dim txt = Me.Controls().Find(textBoxPrefix & suffix, True).Single()
    txt.Visible = chk.Checked
    txt.Text = If(chk.Checked, "", txt.Text)
End Sub
```

Making it a little more scaleable, add handlers to all CheckBoxes in the GroupBox in Form_Load programmatically. (remove `Handles chkBox.CheckedChanged, chkLawn.CheckedChanged, chkPav.CheckedChanged` from the event handler declaration)

```
Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
    ' assuming the GroupBox is named gbTickets, add all handlers programmatically
    For Each chk As CheckBox In Me.gbTickets.Controls.OfType(Of CheckBox)
        AddHandler chk.CheckedChanged, AddressOf chk_CheckedChanged
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove the `chkPav.Checked = True`, `chkLawn.Checked = True` and `chkBox.Checked = True` in your .click events.

Also, i would recommand to use the "CheckStateChanged" vb.net event.